# Detect odd and even rows Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, logical-operators

I need to loop over a dataframe and check if the odd rows of a specific column are equal to a given variable( same for even rows).

This is my code:

```
mydf = pd.read_excel(test.xlsx, header=0, index= False)
mydf = mydf.sort_values(by='Time') 
if ((mydf['Door Name'].iloc[::2]=='RDC_OUT-1') & (mydf['Door Name'].iloc[1::2]=='RDC_IN-1')):
    for i in range (l):
        mydf['diff'] = mydf['Times'].iloc[1::2].to_numpy() - mydf['Times'].iloc[::2]
        Total = mydf['diff'].sum()
        print('Total: ',Total)
```

but when I run it I get this error:

```
if ((mydf['Door Name'].iloc[::2]=='RDC_OUT-1') & (mydf['Door Name'].iloc[1::2]=='RDC_IN-1')):

  File "C:\Users\khoul\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1478, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

this is my dataframe:

[image]

```
 Door name    Time                   Last Name   First Name
 RDC_IN-1     05/08/2019  15:23:00   aa          bb
 RDC_OUT-1    05/08/2019  12:39:00   aa          bb           
 RDC_IN-1     05/08/2019  12:13:00   aa          bb
 RDC_OUT-1    05/08/2019  09:10:00   aa          bb
```

I don't know why it wouldn't accept it!

Comment: Can you add some data sample, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: `mydf.loc[::2,'Door Name']=='RDC_OUT-1'` will work right. But for `mydf['Times'].iloc[1::2].to_numpy() - mydf['Times'].iloc[::2]` you need equal size Series. Are you sure that different conditions get a truly results?

Comment: @splash58 yes, I made an example and its length is even

Comment: @splash58 even with this `mydf.loc[::2,'Door Name']=='RDC_OUT-1'` it did not work, same error

Comment: Could you try to make example of data result to the error. With those from the question all works

Comment: I also worked on that example but it didn't work, however, when I added .all() it worked just fine `elif (((mydf.loc[::2,'Door Name']=='RDC_OUT-1').all()) & (mydf['Door Name'].iloc[1::2]=='RDC_IN-1').all()):`

Comment: (mydf.loc[::2,'Door Name']=='RDC_OUT-1').all()  - mean only that even rows all contain ['Door Name']=='RDC_OUT-1'. but not select anything

Comment: @splash58 can you please explain what do you mean exactly by 'but not select anything'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is first select all sorted rows by `Time` with `RDC_OUT-1` and next `RDC_IN-1` values, another rows are filter out:

```
mydf = df.sort_values(by='Time') 

m1 = mydf['Door name'] == 'RDC_OUT-1'
m2 = mydf['Door name'] == 'RDC_IN-1'

m11 = m1 & m2.shift(-1)
m22 = m1.shift() & m2

df = mydf[m11 | m22]
print (mydf)
   Door name                Time Last Name First Name
3  RDC_OUT-1 2019-05-08 09:10:00        aa         bb
2   RDC_IN-1 2019-05-08 12:13:00        aa         bb
1  RDC_OUT-1 2019-05-08 12:39:00        aa         bb
0   RDC_IN-1 2019-05-08 15:23:00        aa         bb
```

So because get same number of `IN` and `OUT` rows solution from comments should working nice:

```
Total = (df.loc[df['Door name']=='RDC_IN-1','Time'] - 
         df.loc[df['Door name']=='RDC_OUT-1','Time'].to_numpy()).sum()
print('Total: ',Total)
Total:  0 days 05:47:00
```

Comment: thank you, but I need to apply the if condition because this script will be executed on many excel files with different contents, this is just a part of the code

Comment: @A.khou - Can you check completely changed answer?